# HTML Code:Invalid Data is being submitted

Tags: javascript, html

I have written this code where I am validating data in the Registration Form.On submitting the invalid data, this data is still being submitted.I don't want to submit this invalid data.For eg. Name :1234
This Name is invalid.It still gets submitted.
The condition is that I have to use only javascript and HTML.

```js
function formValidation() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var mobile = document.getElementById("mobile").value;
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  var pincode = document.getElementById("pincode").value;
  var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
  var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
  var coursename = document.getElementById("coursename").value;
  var pattern1 = /^\d{6}$/;
  var pattern2 = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  if (name == '') {
    alert('Please enter your name');
  } else if (!letters.test(name)) {
    alert('Name field required only alphabet characters');
  } else if (document.getElementById("name").value.length < 6) {
    alert('Name minimum length is 6');
  } else if (document.getElementById("name").value.length > 33) {
    alert('Name maximum length is 33');
  } else if (email == '') {
    alert('Please enter your user email id');
  } else if (!filter.test(email)) {
    alert('Invalid email');
  } else if (mobile == '') {
    alert('Please enter your mobile');
  } else if (!pattern2.test(mobile)) {
    alert('Mobile Should be 10 digits')
  } else if (address == '') {
    alert('Please enter your address');
  } else if (document.getElementById("address").value.length < 20) {
    alert('Address minimum length is 20');
  } else if (document.getElementById("address").value.length > 32) {
    alert('Address maximum length is 32');
  } else if (pincode == '') {
    alert('Please enter your pincode');
  } else if (!pattern1.test(pincode)) {
    alert('Pincode Should be 6 digits')
  } else if (state == '') {
    alert('Please enter your state');
  } else if (!letters.test(state)) {
    alert('State field required only alphabet characters');
  } else if (document.getElementById("state").value.length < 6) {
    alert('state minimum length is 6');
  } else if (document.getElementById("state").value.length > 33) {
    alert('state maximum length is 33');
  } else if (country == '') {
    alert('Please enter your Country');
  } else if (!letters.test(country)) {
    alert('Country field required only alphabet characters');
  } else if (document.getElementById("country").value.length < 5) {
    alert('Country Name minimum length is 6');
  } else if (document.getElementById("Country").value.length > 33) {
    alert('Country Name maximum length is 33');
  } else if (coursename == '') {
    alert('Please enter your course name');
  } else if (!letters.test(coursename)) {
    alert('Course Name field required only alphabet characters');
  } else if (document.getElementById("name").value.length < 3) {
    alert('Course Name minimum length is 6');
  } else if (document.getElementById("coursename").value.length > 40) {
    alert('Course Name maximum length is 40')
  } else {
    alert('Thank You for Registratione');

  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

input[type=text],
textarea,
input[type=date] {
  width: 96%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

select {
  width: 99%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

input[type=submit],
input[type=reset] {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<h3>STUDENT REGISTRATION FORM</h3>
<form name="registration">
  Applicant Name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Full  Name"><br> Email id:<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email id"><br> Mobile Number:<input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Enter your mobile number"><br>  Address:

  <textarea name="address" id="address" cols="35" rows="4"></textarea><br> Pin Code<input type="text" name="pincode" id="pincode" placeholder="Enter the pincode"><br> State:
  <br><input type="text" name="state" id="state" placeholder="Enter the state name"><br> Country:
  <input type="text" name="country" id="country" placeholder="Enter the name of residing country"><br> Course Name:<input type="text" name="coursename" id="coursename" placeholder="Enter the course name">

  <!-- <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="formValidation()" /> -->
  <button type="submit" onsubmit="formValidation()">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Your function needs to return false in all instances when you want the form NOT to submit.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest you use the `addEventListener` instead of using the HTML for this. A solution with `addEventListener`:

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");

function formValidation() {
   form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
       if(/*your condition is invalid*/) {
           e.preventDefault();
       } else if.....
       //your other validations here
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `onsubmit` function should return false and `preventDefault()` on the event for each case where it fails validation. Your `onsubmit` should also be bound to the `form` element, not the `button`.

I get the impression that this is an assignment for a class, but I would still like to reiterate the point that inline JS is generally bad for both readability and maintainability of your code. If your class permits it, use event listeners.

```js
function formValidation(e) {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var mobile = document.getElementById("mobile").value;
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  var pincode = document.getElementById("pincode").value;
  var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
  var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
  var coursename = document.getElementById("coursename").value;
  var pattern1 = /^\d{6}$/;
  var pattern2 = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  if (name == '') {
    alert('Please enter your name');
  } else if (!letters.test(name)) {
    alert('Name field required only alphabet characters');
  } else if (document.getElementById("name").value.length < 6) {
    alert('Name minimum length is 6');
  } else if (document.getElementById("name").value.length > 33) {
    alert('Name maximum length is 33');
  } else if (email == '') {
    alert('Please enter your user email id');
  } else if (!filter.test(email)) {
    alert('Invalid email');
  } else if (mobile == '') {
    alert('Please enter your mobile');
  } else if (!pattern2.test(mobile)) {
    alert('Mobile Should be 10 digits')
  } else if (address == '') {
    alert('Please enter your address');
  } else if (document.getElementById("address").value.length < 20) {
    alert('Address minimum length is 20');
  } else if (document.getElementById("address").value.length > 32) {
    alert('Address maximum length is 32');
  } else if (pincode == '') {
    alert('Please enter your pincode');
  } else if (!pattern1.test(pincode)) {
    alert('Pincode Should be 6 digits')
  } else if (state == '') {
    alert('Please enter your state');
  } else if (!letters.test(state)) {
    alert('State field required only alphabet characters');
  } else if (document.getElementById("state").value.length < 6) {
    alert('state minimum length is 6');
  } else if (document.getElementById("state").value.length > 33) {
    alert('state maximum length is 33');
  } else if (country == '') {
    alert('Please enter your Country');
  } else if (!letters.test(country)) {
    alert('Country field required only alphabet characters');
  } else if (document.getElementById("country").value.length < 5) {
    alert('Country Name minimum length is 6');
  } else if (document.getElementById("Country").value.length > 33) {
    alert('Country Name maximum length is 33');
  } else if (coursename == '') {
    alert('Please enter your course name');
  } else if (!letters.test(coursename)) {
    alert('Course Name field required only alphabet characters');
  } else if (document.getElementById("name").value.length < 3) {
    alert('Course Name minimum length is 6');
  } else if (document.getElementById("coursename").value.length > 40) {
    alert('Course Name maximum length is 40')
  } else {
    alert('Thank You for Registratione');
    return true;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

input[type=text],
textarea,
input[type=date] {
  width: 96%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

select {
  width: 99%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

input[type=submit],
input[type=reset] {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<h3>STUDENT REGISTRATION FORM</h3>
<form name="registration" onsubmit="formValidation(event)">
  Applicant Name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Full  Name"><br> Email id:<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email id"><br> Mobile Number:<input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Enter your mobile number"><br>  Address:

  <textarea name="address" id="address" cols="35" rows="4"></textarea><br> Pin Code<input type="text" name="pincode" id="pincode" placeholder="Enter the pincode"><br> State:
  <br><input type="text" name="state" id="state" placeholder="Enter the state name"><br> Country:
  <input type="text" name="country" id="country" placeholder="Enter the name of residing country"><br> Course Name:<input type="text" name="coursename" id="coursename" placeholder="Enter the course name">

  <!-- <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="formValidation()" /> -->
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code

```
function formValidation() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var mobile = document.getElementById("mobile").value;
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var pincode = document.getElementById("pincode").value;
    var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
    var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
    var coursename = document.getElementById("coursename").value;
    var pattern1 = /^\d{6}$/;
    var pattern2 = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if (name == '') {
      alert('Please enter your name');
      return false;
    } else if (!letters.test(name)) {
      alert('Name field required only alphabet characters');
      return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById("name").value.length < 6) {
      alert('Name minimum length is 6');
      return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById("name").value.length > 33) {
      alert('Name maximum length is 33');
      return false;
    } else if (email == '') {
      alert('Please enter your user email id');
      return false;
    } else if (!filter.test(email)) {
      alert('Invalid email');
      return false;
    } else if (mobile == '') {
      alert('Please enter your mobile');
      return false;
    } else if (!pattern2.test(mobile)) {
      alert('Mobile Should be 10 digits')
      return false;
    } else if (address == '') {
      alert('Please enter your address');
      return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById("address").value.length < 20) {
      alert('Address minimum length is 20');
      return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById("address").value.length > 32) {
      alert('Address maximum length is 32');
      return false;
    } else if (pincode == '') {
      alert('Please enter your pincode');
      return false;
    } else if (!pattern1.test(pincode)) {
      alert('Pincode Should be 6 digits')
      return false;
    } else if (state == '') {
      alert('Please enter your state');
      return false;
    } else if (!letters.test(state)) {
      alert('State field required only alphabet characters');
      return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById("state").value.length < 6) {
      alert('state minimum length is 6');
      return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById("state").value.length > 33) {
      alert('state maximum length is 33');
      return false;
    } else if (country == '') {
      alert('Please enter your Country');
      return false;
    } else if (!letters.test(country)) {
      alert('Country field required only alphabet characters');
      return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById("country").value.length < 5) {
      alert('Country Name minimum length is 6');
      return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById("Country").value.length > 33) {
      alert('Country Name maximum length is 33');
      return false;
    } else if (coursename == '') {
      alert('Please enter your course name');
      return false;
    } else if (!letters.test(coursename)) {
      alert('Course Name field required only alphabet characters');
      return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById("name").value.length < 3) {
      alert('Course Name minimum length is 6');
      return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById("coursename").value.length > 40) {
      alert('Course Name maximum length is 40')
      return false;
    } else {
      alert('Thank You for Registratione');
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<h3>STUDENT REGISTRATION FORM</h3>
<form name="registration" onsubmit="return formValidation()">
  Applicant Name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Full  Name"><br> Email id:<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email id"><br> Mobile Number:<input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Enter your mobile number"><br>  Address:

  <textarea name="address" id="address" cols="35" rows="4"></textarea><br> Pin Code<input type="text" name="pincode" id="pincode" placeholder="Enter the pincode"><br> State:
  <br><input type="text" name="state" id="state" placeholder="Enter the state name"><br> Country:
  <input type="text" name="country" id="country" placeholder="Enter the name of residing country"><br> Course Name:<input type="text" name="coursename" id="coursename" placeholder="Enter the course name">

  <!-- <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="formValidation()" /> -->
  <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent form submission, first you change the submit button type form `submit` to `button` and then change the event `onsubmit` to `onclick`.

```js
function formValidation() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var mobile = document.getElementById("mobile").value;
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  var pincode = document.getElementById("pincode").value;
  var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
  var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
  var coursename = document.getElementById("coursename").value;
  var pattern1 = /^\d{6}$/;
  var pattern2 = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
   
  if (name == '') {
    alert('Please enter your name');
  } else if (!letters.test(name)) {
    alert('Name field required only alphabet characters');
  } else if (document.getElementById("name").value.length < 6) {
    alert('Name minimum length is 6');
  } else if (document.getElementById("name").value.length > 33) {
    alert('Name maximum length is 33');
  } else if (email == '') {
    alert('Please enter your user email id');
  } else if (!filter.test(email)) {
    alert('Invalid email');
  } else if (mobile == '') {
    alert('Please enter your mobile');
  } else if (!pattern2.test(mobile)) {
    alert('Mobile Should be 10 digits')
  } else if (address == '') {
    alert('Please enter your address');
  } else if (document.getElementById("address").value.length < 20) {
    alert('Address minimum length is 20');
  } else if (document.getElementById("address").value.length > 32) {
    alert('Address maximum length is 32');
  } else if (pincode == '') {
    alert('Please enter your pincode');
  } else if (!pattern1.test(pincode)) {
    alert('Pincode Should be 6 digits')
  } else if (state == '') {
    alert('Please enter your state');
  } else if (!letters.test(state)) {
    alert('State field required only alphabet characters');
  } else if (document.getElementById("state").value.length < 6) {
    alert('state minimum length is 6');
  } else if (document.getElementById("state").value.length > 33) {
    alert('state maximum length is 33');
  } else if (country == '') {
    alert('Please enter your Country');
  } else if (!letters.test(country)) {
    alert('Country field required only alphabet characters');
  } else if (document.getElementById("country").value.length < 5) {
    alert('Country Name minimum length is 6');
  } else if (document.getElementById("Country").value.length > 33) {
    alert('Country Name maximum length is 33');
  } else if (coursename == '') {
    alert('Please enter your course name');
  } else if (!letters.test(coursename)) {
    alert('Course Name field required only alphabet characters');
  } else if (document.getElementById("name").value.length < 3) {
    alert('Course Name minimum length is 6');
  } else if (document.getElementById("coursename").value.length > 40) {
    alert('Course Name maximum length is 40')
  } else {
    alert('Thank You for Registratione');

  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

input[type=text],
textarea,
input[type=date] {
  width: 96%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

select {
  width: 99%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

input[type=submit],
input[type=reset] {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>STUDENT REGISTRATION FORM</h3>
  <form name="registration">
    Applicant Name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Full  Name"><br> Email id:<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email id"><br> Mobile Number:<input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Enter your mobile number"><br>  Address:

    <textarea name="address" id="address" cols="35" rows="4"></textarea><br> Pin Code<input type="text" name="pincode" id="pincode" placeholder="Enter the pincode"><br> State:
    <br><input type="text" name="state" id="state" placeholder="Enter the state name"><br> Country:
    <input type="text" name="country" id="country" placeholder="Enter the name of residing country"><br> Course Name:<input type="text" name="coursename" id="coursename" placeholder="Enter the course name">

    <!-- <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="formValidation()" /> -->
    <button type="button" onClick="formValidation()">Submit</button>

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```